# How to use the query visual builder in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin version 5.0.4 and there seems to be a way to produce SQL queries using a visual tool by selecting a database, then **Query > Query by example > Switch to visual builder**. This shows a diagram of the database relations where I can select individual tables and columns, apparently in order to produce a SQL query, but I'm stuck at this screen and have no idea what to do next in order to generate an actual query:

[image]

Feel like I'm missing something obvious. I've googled this but all I find are paywalled tutorials and books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your report here, we've found a regression with phpMyAdmin and opened a bug report about this problem. You're right, the "Build Query" text is missing. The bug report is at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16485.

As far as actually creating the query, which I'm not sure if that was also part of your question, you can click on the gear icon after each column to decide what factors you want to select by. Then, you would use the "Build Query" button to run the query you've assembled. The "Active options" button in the top right corner lets you see, edit, and delete any of the existing parts of the query you've already compiled.